# Facebook login API or similar thing

Tags: facebook, samsung-smart-tv

Is there any API in facebook if we provide username and password authenticate and return user id, can share on the wall, upload photo etc.

Ah, how awesome if we have something like

```
$facebook = new facebook();
$user = $facebook->lgoin("atestuser@mydomain.com","xY2349");

if($user){
  $facebook->share("Sometext to share on facebook");
}
```

If such thing is not provided, how can we accomplish this?
Remember I am aware of graph API and developing for a device which do not have browser, Can only send ajax request.

Comment: No, login via username/password is not possible via API – and users are strongly discouraged from giving that data to any 3rd party. If you do not have the ability to show the login dialog in something browser-like, then you are out of luck.

Comment: But I can loging using a login form similar to facebook!